# Nginx - extension module for http to tcp

Tags: c++, nginx

I have a scenario, in which i want a 4 tire architecture.

Browser/app --> Web server --> My Server --> DB

In this, my requirement is web server(NGINX) should maintain a single TCP connection with My server. Whenever request is received by NGINX then it should do basic validation and send it to My server. My server will process and send response to NGINX over TCP. NGINX will then send http response to browser/app.
In this NGINX should use event mechanism and should not block the thread till response is received from My server.

Have someone done this type of things. I prefer a c++ extension module to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why do you what to do that?

Comment: Maybe FastCGI or SCGI protocols.